# Testing createAsyncThunk with Mock Service Worker Fails

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, msw

I am new to the **redux-toolkit** and its testing. I am trying to write a test for a `createAsyncThunk` that calls an API and updates the state by the data from the API. My async thunk is being called by a button in my component and rather than testing the thunk itself, I am testing its implementation in my component. I am using the **Mock Service Worker** library to mock my API calls. Following is the screenshot of my failed test 
[image]

Here is the test that I am running

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { rest } from "msw";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "./redux/store";

const server = setupServer(
  rest.get("/api", (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json("10"), ctx.delay(150));
  })
);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.restoreHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

const MockApp: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={createStore()}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
};
it("Should simulate the api call", async () => {
  render(<MockApp />);

  const apiButton = screen.getByText("Api call");

  const counter = await screen.findByTestId("displayCount");

  fireEvent.click(apiButton);
  expect(counter).toHaveTextContent("10");
});
```

My `createAsyncThunk` is quite simple as well

```js
export const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/fetchById",
  // Declare the type your function argument here:
  async (userId: number) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${userId}`
    );
    // Inferred return type: Promise<MyData>
    const res = await response.json();
    return res.userId as MyData["userId"];
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to deal with the async nature of your thunk by waiting until your exception is true, e.g. like so:

```
await waitFor(() => expect(counter).toHaveTextContent("10"))
```

That way the test waits for

- the thunk to do the http call and notify the component consuming it with the result data
- the component to re-render
- the assertion to be true

See the [RTL docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async).

Comment: true. But I have added the wait for the **textContent** to appear but it's not working. I think it has something to do with the mock server.

Comment: Is that line executed during the test? `return res(ctx.json("10"), ctx.delay(150))`? Can you verify that e.g. using a console log?

Comment: As per MSW docs, we need to give the absolute url of the endpoint.
You have given just '/api'. Could you make it absolute path starting from http:// or https://?